# Saving 2 arrays from same class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have this situation where I have one class only: `CUSTOMER` which contains multiple arrays `ADDRESS` and `PRIVACY`. How can I do an insert of both of the arrays?

This is my json customer class

```
"customer": {               
    "address": [
      { 
           "city": "California",
           "country": "USA"
      }
  ],
     "privacy": [
      {
           "username": "James",
           "password": "123"
      }
  ]
}
```

This is my part of code. But with this I keep getting the *'Not enough values for host variables'* error

```
//insert
command= new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO customer"
                          + "(@city,@country,@username,@password)"
                          + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)", DbConnection);
command.Connection = DbConnection;
command.Transaction = transaction;
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//add values
//customer address[]
foreach (var customer_address in customer.address)
{           
  DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", (object)customer_address.city?? DBNull.Value);                 
  DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", (object)customer_address.country ?? DBNull.Value);
}

//customer privacy[]
foreach (var customer_privacy in customer.privacy)
{                 
  DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (object)customer_privacy.username?? DBNull.Value);                                 
  DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", (object)customer_privacy.password?? DBNull.Value);
}
```

And this is how I did the mapping of the Json CUSTOMER class

```
    public class Address
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public List<Address> address { get; set; }
        public List<Privacy> privacy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Privacy
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, you will find coding much easier and more secure if you use Entity Framework Core and Linq. The style you are using leads to a lot of extra code, and has security issues. EF/Linq would also avoid issues like you are having, as you would be populating entity properties, so you'd be able to see exactly what you are and are not setting.

Comment: Can you show your database table `Customer` and see if it matches with the insert query?

Comment: Why are you setting `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`? Your command is a simple SQL query, not stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this:

```
    string userName;
    string pwd;

    string cityName;
    string countryName;

//Loop privacy
    foreach (var customer_privacy in customer.privacy)
                                {
                                    userName = customer_privacy.username;
                                    pwd = customer_privacy.password;
                                }
    
// insert privacy
                           DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (object)userName ?? DBNull.Value);
                                DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", (object)pwd ?? DBNull.Value);
                           
//Loop address
foreach (var customer_address in customer.address)
                                {
                                    countryName = customer_privacy.country;
                                    cityName = customer_privacy.city;
                                }
    
// insert address
                           DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", (object)countryName ?? DBNull.Value);
                                DbCommandInsertLeads.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", (object)cityName ?? DBNull.Value);
```